# Dialog flow to skype Integration error

Tags: integration, skype, dialogflow-es

> Dialog flow to skype Integration error- There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code BadRequest
>   [There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code BadRequest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhI2C.jpg)

**is anyone has fixed this issue as the bot is sending the request from skype but from dialog side we don't see any reply **

Comment: I am also seeing same error. If you anyone come across fix, please advise.